# Processing, making an analog clock, the numbers

Tags: java, processing

so, as an assaignment i want to make an analog clock, and i am pretty far. I only need the numbers around the clock, but i cant figure out how to make these. I have made some dots right now, but i want to replace theese with the numbers 1-12.. does any1 know an easy and fast way of doing this? my code is as following:

```
    int cx, cy;
float secondsRadius;
float minutesRadius;
float hoursRadius;
float clockDiameter;

void setup() {
  size(1366,768);
  stroke(255);

  float radius = min(width/1.2, height/1.2) / 2;
  secondsRadius = radius * 0.72;
  minutesRadius = radius * 0.60;
  hoursRadius = radius * 0.50;
  clockDiameter = radius * 1.8;

  cx = width / 2;
  cy = height / 2;
}

void draw() {
  background(random(0,255),random(0,255),random(0,255));

  // Draw the clock background
  fill(0);
  noStroke();
  ellipse(cx, cy, clockDiameter, clockDiameter);

  // Angles for sin() and cos() start at 3 o'clock;
  // subtract HALF_PI to make them start at the top
  float s = map(second(), 0, 60, 0, TWO_PI) - HALF_PI;
  float m = map(minute() + norm(second(), 0, 60), 0, 60, 0, TWO_PI) - HALF_PI; 
  float h = map(hour() + norm(minute(), 0, 60), 0, 24, 0, TWO_PI * 2) - HALF_PI;

  // Draw the hands of the clock
  stroke(255);
  strokeWeight(1);
  line(cx, cy, cx + cos(s) * secondsRadius, cy + sin(s) * secondsRadius);
  strokeWeight(2);
  line(cx, cy, cx + cos(m) * minutesRadius, cy + sin(m) * minutesRadius);
  strokeWeight(4);
  line(cx, cy, cx + cos(h) * hoursRadius, cy + sin(h) * hoursRadius);

  // Draw the dots arround the clock
  strokeWeight(2);
  beginShape(POINTS);
  for (int a = 0; a < 360; a+=30) {
    float angle = radians(a);
    float x = cx + cos(angle) * secondsRadius;
    float y = cy + sin(angle) * secondsRadius;
    vertex(x, y);
  }
  endShape();
  textSize(40);
    text("Dank Clock", 570,40);
}
```

Comment: i am using Java, thorugh Processing :-)

Comment: @FlorianAlbrecht OP is using Processing (http://processing.org) which is based on Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have a loop that goes around the clock and places dots at the clock positions. Now all you need is some logic that draws the hour at those positions.

Processing has a `text()` function that allows you to draw text (or numbers) to the screen. You can just call that instead of `vertex()` to draw the hours.

To get the hours to draw, just use an `int` variable that you increment each time through the loop. Something like this:

```
  int hour = 3;
  for (int a = 0; a < 360; a+=30) {
    float angle = radians(a);
    float x = cx + cos(angle) * secondsRadius;
    float y = cy + sin(angle) * secondsRadius;
    vertex(x, y);
    fill(255);

    text(hour, x, y);
    hour++;
    if(hour > 12){
      hour = 1;
    }
  }
```

Notice that I'm starting at `3` because your angle starts at `0`, which points all the way to the right. When the loop goes over the 12, I just start `hour` back over at `1`.

You could probably also figure out a simple formula that maps from `a` to an hour, that way you don't have to do the incrementing yourself.